# how can I save the image with transparent background

Tags: image, matplotlib, background, python-3.7, transparent

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png', dpi=100, transparent = True)  
buf.seek(0)
plt.close()
```

I can't save the image with a transparent background. 
Help me please!! Thanks

Comment: The command is correct, how have you checked, that it is not transparent?

Comment: yes, I realized that saving it in the buffer with the io.BytesIO () command, the background transparency did not work. I saved it on the desktop and then deleted it. But now I don't know how to superimpose the transparent Fit image on the Scatter distribution